# Opening JarFile issue

Tags: c#, jar, executable-jar

I've attempted to run an executable jar for the past hour, but I get the standard error `Cannot access jarfile <jarpath>`. After a while, I have determined that it was a quote problem, as the path contains spaces.

However, I store the path in a string variable, and when I try to concatenate the string that contains the path to the jar with double quotes, it still fails. How should I solve this?

To illustrate:

```
string path = /* %appdata% folder */ + ""\\Application Name\\" + "Application.jar";

//add the double quotes
path = path + "\"";
path += "\"";

Process javaProcess = new Process()

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "javaw";
startInfo.Arguments = @"-jar " + path;

//startInfo.Arguments = @"-jar" + "\"C:...\\Application\\Application.jar\"";
//this one works, though

javaProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;
javaProcess.Start(); //Fails - cannot access jarfile!
```

Answer (score 0):

When running a .jar file in command line, you omit the .jar at the end of the filename.

```
javaw -jar Application
```

Comment: Actually, no - files must have an extension of jar to run. Just checked with the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I be stupid. Really stupid.

I solved it guys. In my code, I used `System.IO.Path` to combine my paths, but that actually screwed up the path such that `javaw` could not recognize the path. Thus, I changed it to:

`string path = "\"" + %appdata% + fileName + "\"";`

And it works just fine.